# What to do with lemon given at Durga temples?

Tags: temple, worship, goddess, puja, durga

Few temples in south India offer lemons to the Village goddess (a form of Durga/kaali) while worshipping.

When I went to a temple yesterday, they are giving lemons each to all the devotees.

What is the actual story behind offering lemons to goddesses and what to do when we receive them from temple management?

Comment: I was once told lemons offered in south at marriage ceremonies/temple to be made as  juice and taken with water and sugar in order to quench the thirst after long summer journeys.

Comment: It is lokachar where lemon is considered to be an equivalent for human head. Just keep the lemon in your house as prasadam Or do its Visarjan in any nearby water body. PS- do not throw it outside on Road or dustbins.

Comment: If it's prasad then you have to deal with it with due respect .. either keep it in your own Puja place or flow it into a river or lake. Do not do anything else with it.

Answer (score 0):

Devotees should prepare juice from the lemons offered to them as prasadam and consume with full devotion. This is what the priest told me upon asking in Kolaramma temple at Kolar .