Can we regularly offer lemon Bali to maa Durga?
How can one give Bali to maa Durga while chanting the 32 names of the goddess?
Also can we give the Bali as a Nitya Upasana or is it relevant only during the Navaratri?
Is it necessary to take a sankalpa to get the benefits or can one do the Bali without any specific sankalpa and still get the benefits?

In south India, giving lemon Diya to Ma is very popular. So I believe it can be done any time. Though few references says about rakukalam. Sankalpa make a vrata stronger and make an aspirant more focused. For nitha puja not recommended but it’s choice of Upasaka. Check few lemon Bali posts and post by Rickross in the community.

Lemon Diya: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52524/what-to-do-with-lemon-given-at-durga-temples
